# Docker image composition COPY command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am building a docker image and need to include some contents from particular url.
So I make a curl request and get the contents as a zip. I am able to extract the zip into a folder as well.
However in the very next line if I try to copy the folder I get error that such file or folder does not exist.
Can someone help me?
Below is the docker file. If I do a ls -a after the unzip I can see 2 items drop and amui which is correct. But very next line if I try to copy it fails.

```
# escape=`

# Setup arguments
ARG BuildConfiguration=Release
ARG ASSEMBLY_VERSION=0.0
ARG FILE_VERSION=0.0.0.0
ARG NUGET_CONFIG=NuGet.config
ARG SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN

# base image stage
 FROM abc.io/aspnet-runtime:3.1.6 AS base

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
FROM abc.io/dotnet-build:3.1.6 AS build

ARG BuildConfiguration
ARG ASSEMBLY_VERSION
ARG FILE_VERSION
ARG NUGET_CONFIG
ARG SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
ENV BuildConfiguration=$BuildConfiguration `
    ASSEMBLY_VERSION=$ASSEMBLY_VERSION `
    FILE_VERSION=$FILE_VERSION `
    NUGET_CONFIG=$NUGET_CONFIG `
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN=$SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN

WORKDIR /build

RUN Write-Host "BuildConfiguration: ${env:BuildConfiguration}"; `
    Write-Host "ASSEMBLY_VERSION: ${env:ASSEMBLY_VERSION}"; `
    Write-Host "FILE_VERSION: ${env:FILE_VERSION}"; `
    Write-Host "NUGET_CONFIG: ${env:NUGET_CONFIG}"; `
    Write-Host "SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: ${env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN}";

RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y aspnetcore-runtime-3.1
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y unzip

FROM build as drop
RUN curl -o drop -u sdf@dise.com:ydfesdfasdfdf56pxvwnd5z6445l7kgezpb2lky6ja2g6xvtina4a --request GET 'https://abe.com/ded/c8002d3e-f4a9-4aea-9ab8-230027996c53/_apis/build/builds/1133376/artifacts?artifactName=drop&api-version=6.0&%24format=zip' -L 
RUN unzip drop -d amui 
COPY amui .
```

Here is the output of the docker build command. Entire output is not shown for sake of brevity.

```
100 18.8M    0 18.8M    0     0   757k      0 --:--:--  0:00:25 --:--:--  450k
100 20.4M    0 20.4M    0     0   784k      0 --:--:--  0:00:26 --:--:--  573k
100 20.7M    0 20.7M    0     0   774k      0 --:--:--  0:00:27 --:--:--  543k
100 21.1M    0 21.1M    0     0   759k      0 --:--:--  0:00:28 --:--:--  582k
100 21.7M    0 21.7M    0     0   764k      0 --:--:--  0:00:29 --:--:--  795k
Removing intermediate container 5cf617b55a61
 ---> 79d3a513aaf3
Step 25/45 : RUN unzip drop -d amui
 ---> Running in d1c070949cf9
Archive:  drop
   creating: amui/drop/
   creating: amui/drop/amui/
 inflating: amui/drop/SQL/Sql.Template.json  
Removing intermediate container d1c070949cf9
 ---> 73959bf35eca
Step 26/45 : COPY amui src/I.C.AM.C.P
Service 'p.am.ui' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder955237576/amui: no such file or directory
```

Comment: in `COPY amui .` the directory `amui` references to a directory on the *host*  while building the image. If you want to copy inside the image you can do `RUN cp ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the file or folder is present in the location you expect it to be. The `WORKDIR /app` from the `FROM abc.io/aspnet-runtime:3.1.6 AS base` sets the working directory for **all** contexts until there's another `WORKDIR` encountered, thus even for the ones that "inherit" from the previous one (`FROM previous as new`) or for the `RUN` context. Once that is out of the way, for the remaining part it's about contexts created by `FROM` and its order.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/7 : FROM alpine as base
 ---> 6dbb9cc54074
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /hello
 ---> Running in 5b7f95f0d20b
Removing intermediate container 5b7f95f0d20b
 ---> 0f139883db01
Step 3/7 : RUN pwd
 ---> Running in 1a6d896f621b
/hello
Removing intermediate container 1a6d896f621b
 ---> a09834ecd175
Step 4/7 : RUN cd /
 ---> Running in 3e6f35bf70e1
Removing intermediate container 3e6f35bf70e1
 ---> 9636932e3f16
Step 5/7 : RUN pwd
 ---> Running in fa5dc0c60493
/hello
Removing intermediate container fa5dc0c60493
 ---> 1d2630c5a098
Step 6/7 : FROM base as test
 ---> 1d2630c5a098
Step 7/7 : RUN pwd
 ---> Running in fabd6c1e82f8
/hello
Removing intermediate container fabd6c1e82f8
 ---> b39b67911581
Successfully built b39b67911581
```

`COPY` is for external files i.e. OUT of the image filesystem/context, on your host system and relative to the context path you specify for the `docker build [...] <context>` (or relative to the `WORKDIR` of a previous stage IIRC, use absolute paths if unsure).

So the case is one of this:

- you already have the contents in your image and you want to use the last context created by `FROM base as drop` (including the curl+unzip trash) for the final image `->` use `RUN cp`
- you want to drop the trash created by curl+unzip `->` use new `FROM` (probably `FROM base`) to create a new context and finalize the previous one, **then** copy from the previous image with `COPY --from=drop amui <dest>`

  > Optionally COPY accepts a flag --from=<name> that can be used to set the source location to a previous build stage (created with FROM .. AS <name>) that will be used instead of a build context sent by the user. In case a build stage with a specified name can't be found an image with the same name is attempted to be used instead. ([source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy))

Order of the `FROM` directives **matters**. If you want to copy to `base` image from `drop`, then `FROM ... AS drop` needs to be built prior to the `FROM ... AS base`. You are basically using one image for building and then you want to continue building upon it:

```
FROM [...] AS base  # creates context for "base"
...
<base image created>

FROM base AS drop  # creates context for "drop"
<download>
COPY ...
<drop image created>
```

but you haven't started a new context (as you want to copy from the ***previous*** context - and you're still either building it or simply misusing `COPY` for `RUN cp`) for the final image, therefore even if you use `COPY --from=...` correctly, you're still copying to the wrong context.

Try this:

```
FROM [...] AS base  # creates context for "base"
...
<base image created>

FROM base AS drop  # creates context for "drop"
<download>
<drop image created>

FROM base  # creates a new, unnamed context
COPY --from=drop ...
<final image created>
```

The last `FROM` context is used for the final image built with:

```
docker build --tag <name> [other options] <context path>
```

Example:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048kB
Step 1/7 : FROM alpine as base
---> 6dbb9cc54074
Step 2/7 : RUN mkdir content;echo "hello" > content/file.txt
---> Running in 1f1a82201436
Removing intermediate container 1f1a82201436
---> 35b7a54e6952
Step 3/7 : FROM base as drop
---> 35b7a54e6952
Step 4/7 : RUN echo "world" > content/file.txt
---> Running in e5b214cad371
Removing intermediate container e5b214cad371
---> 51a3a090f43a
Step 5/7 : FROM base
---> 35b7a54e6952
Step 6/7 : COPY --from=drop content content
---> e4280a26c86f
Step 7/7 : RUN cat content/file.txt
---> Running in d71a121a7ff9
world
Removing intermediate container d71a121a7ff9
---> 760e756c4c11
Successfully built 760e756c4c11
```

Comment: Will try and let you know shortly

Comment: @ckv Note that with non-alphabetical characters in the path you might want to encapsulate it in quotes and/or escape them depending on your shell and however Golang depends to bork (Docker version specific). I experienced some funny stuff with really old Docker versions.

Comment: Tried as per your advice. Still getting same error. Step 26/46 : RUN ls -a
 ---> Running in 39071182f44f
.
..
amui
drop
Removing intermediate container 39071182f44f
 ---> ebd1ad34c138
Step 27/46 : COPY amui --from=drop .
Service 'p.am.ui' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder485994447/amui: no such file or directory and this is the command
RUN unzip drop -d amui 
RUN ls -a
COPY amui --from=drop .

Comment: @ckv Try to swap the `FROM` order and download the file first, then with the correct `FROM` context copy from the previous, staged image.

Comment: @ckv `--from` is *right* after `COPY`, not after the path.

Comment: Tried that also getting different error.
Step 27/46 : COPY --from=drop amui .
Service 'p.am.ui' failed to build: invalid from flag value drop: pull access denied for drop, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Comment: @ckv Check also the order of `FROM` directives and ensure you are copying to the correct image / using the correct `FROM` context (see update).

Comment: Well thats right. I need it in my final image.

Comment: @ckv IF the `FROM build as drop` starts the context of the final image, then you're just misusing `COPY` because you already **are** in the context of your final image, thus just use `RUN cp` instead of `COPY` as you don't want to copy 1) from host 2) from previous image/stage. Otherwise add new `FROM` for the new context.

Comment: @ckv Ping :) See the updates again, hopefully it's clear now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237643/discussion-between-peter-badida-and-ckv).

Comment: Discussion gave me clue and was able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

To change files that are inside the image you should use:

```
RUN cp filename path
```

you can "debug" using `RUN echo "your path:" pwd` and `RUN echo "folders:" ls`, and iteratively navigate and check your path to see if it is correct. Just remember to erase these lines from your Dockerfile and build again.

You also can make it **after build** with:

```
docker images
```

get your image name and tag

```
docker run --privileged  -i  -t  image_name:image_tag bash
```

navigate trough the image, copy, modify, git clone etc ...

exit container and run:

```
docker ps -a
```

to get the image id from the container you just leaved.  Then run:

```
docker commit [image id] image_name_you_choose:tag
```

to save the images changes.